# Why are Maps returned by a JAX-WS call always empty?

Tags: java, web-services, dictionary, jax-ws

My web service method returns a `Page` object which includes the following methods:

```
public Map<String,String[]> getParameters() { ... }
public setParameters(Map<String,String[]> parameters) { ... }
```

On the client side, the JAX-WS generated `getParameters()` method returns a `Parameters` object which provides a `getEntry()` method that returns a `List<Entry>`. However, this list is always empty. What is the cause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use concrete types instead of interfaces in setters and getters:

```
public HashMap<String,String[]> getParameters() { ... }
public setParameters(HashMap<String,String[]> parameters) { ... }
```

Then, everything works as expected.